# Displaying active list in tkinter window class

Tags: python, list, class, user-interface, tkinter

I'm using tkinter to create a GUI for a component inventory application I'm making. The GUI will print the current active list for the program. I'm using a class for the main window, and I'm having trouble displaying the current list after loading a new one.

```
def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        self.pack()
        self.active_list = []
        self.dir = os.getcwd()
        
        self.create_window()
```

In the code above, I initialized the active_list as an empty list. When a new list is opened, it sets the active_list to the new list from a csv file. The class' `show_list()` method below prints the active_list in a text box on the GUI. The main issue is that it doesn't update when a new list is loaded. It can print the empty active_list that is initialized in the `__init__()` func but cannot seem to be updated.

```
def show_list(self):
        self.scrlbr1 = tk.Scrollbar(self.master)
        self.disp_list = tk.Text(self.master, height=5, width=50)

        if not self.active_list:
            self.disp_list.insert(tk.END, 'no list loaded')
        else:
            self.disp_list.insert(tk.END, self.active_list)
        
        
        self.scrlbr1.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)
        self.disp_list.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.Y)
```

My initial thought was that the tk mainloop func was resetting the active_list to an empty list when the class was created. Could anybody suggest some fixes? Thanks

Comment: You should provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You need a mechanism to check if the list was modified, or maybe more simply, a mechanism to refresh the display at regular intervals.

Maybe like this:

```
def __init__(self, master=None):
    super().__init__(master)
    ...
    self.create_show_list_widgets()
    

def create_show_list_widgets(self):
    """creates the widgets used to display the list
    """
    self.scrlbr1 = tk.Scrollbar(self.master)
    self.disp_list = tk.Text(self.master, height=5, width=50)

    self.scrlbr1.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)
    self.disp_list.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.Y)

    self.show_list()


def show_list(self):
    """refreshes the display of the list every second
    """
    if not self.active_list:
        self.disp_list.insert(tk.END, 'no list loaded')
    else:
        self.disp_list.insert(tk.END, self.active_list)
    self.after(1000, self.show_list)    # assuming your class is a subclass of `tk.Tk`, or `tk.Frame`
```